# Storing special (phonetic alphabet) characters in a PostgreSQL column

Tags: postgresql, sqldatatypes

I'd like to create a column to store the phonetic transcriptions of certain phrases in English. For example:

```
column1                |    column2
What do you suggest?   |    ˈwʌ dʊ jʊ səˈdʒɛst?
No problem.            |    noʊ ˈprɑb ləm.
```

and so on. These are the characters of the International Phonetic Alphabet, the same characters used in certain dictionaries. I think they're part of the UTF-8 encoding (at least I think they are since I was able to insert them in a text file by using digraphs in the Vim text editor).

The stress on certain words is marked with an apostrophe which I think is quite evil symbol in the SQL world.

My question is, is there any chance I can store these kind of characters in a PostgreSQL TEXT field? Do I need to enable some special flag?

Comment: **[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e5baf486c21c55dcfa9dec2ea5e99dcb)**

Comment: "*is there any chance I can store these kind of characters in a PostgreSQL TEXT field*" yes without problems

Comment: The apostrophe isn't evil in SQL, it is just used for string literals so you need to properly quote them (i.e. `'noʊ ''prɑb ləm'`); whatever interface you're using to talk to the database should take care of all that if you use placeholders. Also, looks like you have a primary stress marker (`\u02C8`) rather than an apostrophe (`\u0027`).